# Firebase Offline Store - Query not returning changes in online store

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’m using `Firebase` with the offline ability set to true.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath(“my data”).child(“my users id”)
scoresRef.keepSynced(true)
```

This path also has keep Synced set to true, as with out this with changes in the database are not seen within the app immediately as it is using the local cache.

I have another top level node / path in my app that I want to search - containing other users.

I want to use a singleEvent query and find an email address, I’m doing this via

```
studios.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue(email).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in  // etc
```

**I am able to find the node, however I keep getting the local cached version and not the most recent one in the firebase online store.**

If I make some changes to the node online, I don’t get these back within the fetch.

If I changed my fetch to a monitor type i.e.

```
studios.queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue(email).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in  // etc
```

**I get the local cache node first, then get the online updated version as well.**

I would rather use the SingleEvent fetch, but I don’t want to monitor the users entire node with keepSynced as it is a high level node and I don’t want to keep all that data locally, as its not directly related to the user.

One fix I found was prior to the single query was add .keepSynced(true) and in the completion block add .keepSynced(false). I'm not sure how much of the node is downloaded this was and may as well use the monitor fetch rather than the singleEvent.

Should I just use the monitorEvent or is there a better way to use SingleEventFetch that goes to the online store and instead of just returning my local node.

PS I am online and this is confirmed via

```
var connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath(".info/connected")
connectedRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool
    if connected != nil && connected! {
        println("Connected")
    } else {
        println("Not connected")
    }
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here its infuriating

Comment: Agree. There should be an option to bypass cache.