# Firebase: How to use observeSingleEventOfType for latest server data when persistance is enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I really enjoy coding with Firebase. It's a great backend with a variety of different toolsets. But I miss a simple way to check a path for updated data when persistance is enabled. I think that this is not a seldom usecase, because I often need my app to act in a certain way depending on the latest server data, that only need to be read once.

I would usually use `observeSingleEventOfType`, but it's quite useless when perisistance is enabled, since it [will never retrieve the latest server data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276499/what-actually-happens-when-persistence-is-enabled-in-firebase/37280451#37280451). Which I don't understand why. There should be an option added to skip the local cache and only look for server data.

Disabling persistance solves this problem and `observeSingleEventOfType` will work as expected. But that would mean that one needs to reimplement all the offline capabilities on his own.

**First scenario:**

```
 // chats contain meta information about the chat like last message and count of unread messages

 let chatRef = ref.child("chats").child(receiverId).child(chatId)
 chatRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
     if !snapshot.exists() {
         print("snapshot does not exist")
         // the other side has deleted the chat
         // now delete all messages and member objects

         ref.child("messages").child(chatId).setValue(nil)
         ref.child("members").child(chatId).setValue(nil)
     } else {
         print("snapshot exists")
     }
 })
```

I also tried `chatRef.keepSynced(true)` before observing for events with no luck. Which doesn't make sense in all situations anyway:

**Second scenario:**

```
func removeOlderMessages() {
    let dateInThePast = NSDate().addDays(-30).timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
    self.messagesRef.queryOrderedByChild("timestamp")
        .queryEndingAtValue(dateInThePast)
        .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            snapshot.ref.removeValue()
    })
}
```

Using `keepSynced` here would lead to downloading all messages in `messagesRef`, which is not wanted at all.

So is there a clever workaround for these two scenarios? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847265/firebase-offline-store-query-not-returning-changes-in-online-store

Comment: Yes, we definetely need a solution for this. I am curious if Firebase is already working on features enabling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think I found a reasonable workaround for both scenarios:

**Workaround for first scenario:**

Use `transactions`. They will only work when you are online. The `completition` block will return the latest server data.

```
self.ref.child("chats").child(receiverId).child(chatId).runTransactionBlock({ (currentData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
    // Actually do nothing with the retrieved data and re-submit it.
    return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
 }) { (error, success, snapshot) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    } else if !success || snapshot == nil {
       return
    }

    // snapshot contains the latest server data
    if !snapshot!.exists() {
       // the other side has deleted the chat
       // now delete all messages and member objects

       print("snapshot doesn't exist. deleting messages and members.")
       ref.child("messages").child(chatId).setValue(nil)
       ref.child("members").child(chatId).setValue(nil)     
    } else {
       print("snapshot exists. not deleting all messages and members.")
    }     
}
```

The downside is that it will take considerably longer to retrieve the data compared to `observeEventType` or `observeSingleEventOfType`.

**Workaround for second scenario:**

Use `observeEventType(.Value)`. It will first return the cached and then latest server data if available. The observer can be removed after a set time interval with `NSTimer`.

All in all these workarounds are ok for now, but a function to skip the local cache when using `observeSingleEventOfType` is indispensable.

Comment: quick question! When writing data using firebase transaction, if the device's internet connection drops immediately after the write was made, just before a response is sent to the client, will the server send the response back when user goes online again? Ex: internet drops just before this line `}) { (error, success, snapshot) in`. Another scenario, internet drops immediately before `if !snapshot!.exists()`. What happens here? your function won't continue evaluating? So your app will remain in inconsistent state, right? Many thanks